# Расписание занятий едет верстка при добавлении дней недели

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Ситуация следующая: я не программист, но для работы нужен сайт (если быть точнее, то какое то готовое адаптивное решение для расписания занятий). Нашел очень неплохой готовый вариант на данном ресурсе: https://codyhouse.co/gem/schedule-template

Так вот, все скачал, скопировал код соответственно где надо. В целом все работает идеально. Но вот момент, который мне так и не удается реализовать: при добавлении дополнительных дней (СБ и ВС), то они сползают вниз и никак не хотят выстраиваться в одну строчку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже перепробовал все варианты самостоятельно, но может кто то из специалистов сможет мне более грамотно помочь сделать это? Сразу хочу поблагодарить тех, кто отзовется!

Comment: а причем здесь bootstrap?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос [mcve], чтобы помочь вам, нужно увидеть как вы добавляете выходные, чтобы понять в чем загвоздка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ячейкам в вашей таблице жестко прописана ширина:

```
.cd-schedule .events .events-group {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Сейчас 20% - это если 5 дней.

Если у вас 7 дней, то укажите свою ширину ячейкам: 100/7 = 14.2857%.

```
.cd-schedule .events .events-group {
  width: 14.2857%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: А можно проще `width: calc((100% - 2px) / 7);` (- 2px, т.к. `border: 1px ...`)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 таки да, уже [можно](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc). Хотя у меня некоторые еще на почти умерших старичках настаивают.

Comment: ого, только сейчас узнал что этот способ поддержку имеет :D